# overflow issues on real mobile device

Tags: css, responsive

Im trying to create a mobile view of my software. everything works fine on google mobile emulator and other mobile emulator plugins.
This is how it looks on the emulator: [Emulator view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OssGp.png)

Now, when I access it on a real device. it looks like this.
[Real mobile device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXGy9.jpg). 
As you can see, unlike on the emulator view, the box at the bottom did not go to the bottom-most part of the page even though I set it to **position absolute, bottom 0**, also, there are no paddings and margins to the main container.

Comment: Try adding `min-height: 100vh` to `body`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `.class_div {position:absolute;bottom:0; left:0;}`, it will do so, with relation to its parent. If the parent is not touching the bottom screen, the inside item (with position:absolute) also won't.

If you instead use `position:fixed`, it takes its anchor as `html tag` so it would always touch bottom.

```css
.p1 {background: yellow; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}
.div1 {position:relative; background: pink; height:100px; width:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <p class="p1">Hello</p>
</div>
```

`position:absolute` is no guarantee of touching your screen's bottom. It will depend where its parent (parent with position:relative) resides and what are its dimensions, and where does it sit?

Comment: Good thinking! I would like to add that I'm not a fan of `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` and recommend you make the page height 100% and use something like Flexbox with `align-self: flex-end` for the positioning, since that makes placing more elements on your page easier. `position: absolute` makes the calculation of relative components very hard.